# Error installing xml2 in R (Unable to load shared object)

Tags: r, linux, centos

Let's start with, i am pretty new to both linux (CentOS) and R.

I was given a task to install xml2 package, for that i ran

> `install.packages("xml2")`

and error occured

```
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading'
** help
Error : unable to load shared object '/home/<username>/R/x86_64-redaht-linux-gnu-library/3.6/00LOCK-xml2/00new/xml2/libs.so':
libicui18n.so.58: cannot open shared obejct file: No such file or directory
Error: installaing RD objects failed for package 'xml2'
* removing '/home/<username>/R/x86_64-redaht-linux-gnu-library/3.6/xml2'
```

Then i went ahead and did some research on this issue and found much (maybe to resolve it), but couldn't really understand because of lack of knowledge.

So first thing i did was to search if i even have **libicui18n.so.58** by doing `locate libicui18n` and could find something but not 58.

So I started by downloading ICU 58 source and compiling it manually.

It was successfully done.

Still, there was a same error. Although i could find  **libicui18n.so.58** by doing `locate libicui18n` this time.

Now i'm lost because there are so many locations where it shows all the versions of libicui18n.so.58.

Also, when i do `$LD_LOCATION_PATH`, there's nothing for the output.

Please, if you could, explain it to me what i need to do to resolve it now.

Also, the output of locate command is:

````
/home/Zach/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/libicui18n.so.56
/home/Zach/Downloads/test/icu-release-58-3/icu4c/source/lib/libicui18n.so
/home/Zach/Downloads/test/icu-release-58-3/icu4c/source/lib/libicui18n.so.58
/home/Zach/Downloads/test/icu-release-58-3/icu4c/source/lib/libicui18n.so.58.3
/opt/anaconda3/lib/libicui18n.so
/opt/anaconda3/lib/libicui18n.so.58
/opt/anaconda3/lib/libicui18n.so.58.2
/opt/anaconda3/pkgs/icu-58.2-h9c2bf20_1/lib/libicui18n.so
/opt/anaconda3/pkgs/icu-58.2-h9c2bf20_1/lib/libicui18n.so.58
/opt/anaconda3/pkgs/icu-58.2-h9c2bf20_1/lib/libicui18n.so.58.2
/opt/anaconda3/pkgs/icu-58.2-he6710b0_3/lib/libicui18n.so
/opt/anaconda3/pkgs/icu-58.2-he6710b0_3/lib/libicui18n.so.58
/opt/anaconda3/pkgs/icu-58.2-he6710b0_3/lib/libicui18n.so.58.2
/root/opt/lib/libicui18n.so
/root/opt/lib/libicui18n.so.58
/root/opt/lib/libicui18n.so.58.2
/root/opt/pkgs/icu-58.2-h9c2bf20_1/lib/libicui18n.so
/root/opt/pkgs/icu-58.2-h9c2bf20_1/lib/libicui18n.so.58
/root/opt/pkgs/icu-58.2-h9c2bf20_1/lib/libicui18n.so.58.2
/usr/lib/rstudio/lib/libicui18n.so.56
/usr/lib64/libicui18n.so
/usr/lib64/libicui18n.so.50
/usr/lib64/libicui18n.so.50.2
/usr/lib64/webkit2gtk-4.0/libicui18n.so.57
/usr/lib64/webkit2gtk-4.0/libicui18n.so.57.1
/usr/local/lib/libicui18n.so
/usr/local/lib/libicui18n.so.58
/usr/local/lib/libicui18n.so.58.3
/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8aab92bb1b0ffb1addfc835da5c31c169d7af7cc5c825a93f529ab8d4c9cdead/diff/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.66
/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8aab92bb1b0ffb1addfc835da5c31c169d7af7cc5c825a93f529ab8d4c9cdead/diff/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.66.1
/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d445cc4c7c11f7e66bcd0f198287e6b6830b33099fcfe884bc3d0e57d0116c16/diff/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.67
/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d445cc4c7c11f7e66bcd0f198287e6b6830b33099fcfe884bc3d0e57d0116c16/diff/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.67.1
/var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.kde.Platform/x86_64/5.11/02ede84d3591a5ea8028204d86059bffaccb778159ec53c859bbc60d9e7025e8/files/lib/libicui18n.so.57
/var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.kde.Platform/x86_64/5.11/02ede84d3591a5ea8028204d86059bffaccb778159ec53c859bbc60d9e7025e8/files/lib/libicui18n.so.57.1
/volumes/user/home/Zach/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/libicui18n.so.56
/volumes/user/home/Zach/Downloads/test/icu-release-58-3/icu4c/source/lib/libicui18n.so
/volumes/user/home/Zach/Downloads/test/icu-release-58-3/icu4c/source/lib/libicui18n.so.58
/volumes/user/home/Zach/Downloads/test/icu-release-58-3/icu4c/source/lib/libicui18n.so.58.3```
````

Comment: Your question is specific to your computer and thus hard to debug from the outside. I would just run R in a docker container [rocker/verse](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/verse) holding all libraries separated from the rest of your system.

Comment: Did you `sudo ldconfig` after building /usr/local/lib/libicui18n.so.58? It is something I often forget, and worth rebuilding and finalizing with that if you've already closed the terminal where you built...Probably voodoo.

Comment: thanks for the comment, but sorry, i couldn't understand.
should i `sudo ldconfig`, and i don't know what is building means here.

i just had to run a command and that command throwed an error relating to **libicui18n.so.58**, please if you could help me understand it properly.